# GLib - difference between class_init and init class methods

Tags: c, glib

I'm a newbie with glib and I'm still struggling to understand the difference between `my_class_name_class_init()` methods and `my_class_name_init()` methods.

I get that the latter is kinda equivalent to a C++ constructor and that goes per-instance of the object created but I don't quite understand the purpose of those `my_class_name_class_init()` methods. By reading [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject-construction.html) I think `class_init()` methods are somewhat similar to a static constructor valid for all instances but I'm still not sure I got this right.

What's the purpose of `class_init()` methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`class_init` functions are executed once per class, [before first instance is constructed](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/chapter-gobject.html#gobject-construction-table) - in that way they are similar to [C# static constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors). In contrast, `instance_init` functions are called for every instance of object created and are responsible for initializing that instance.

Like static constructors, `class_init` are responsible for initializing any shared data all instances might need, but more importantly, in GObject they play vital role in setting up GObject object system. They are responsible for:

- [Setting up virtual function tables](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject-methods.html#virtual-public-methods)
- [Setting up GObject property system](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-properties.html)
- [Setting up signals](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/signal.html)